# What is the difference between "arr[i] ^= 1" and "arr[i] ^1" about XOR?

Tags: java, xor, bitmask

When I write like below

```
int [] test = {4};
int a = test[0]^=1;
int b = test[0]^1;
```

I can get this output.

OUTPUT

```
test[0]^=1 : 5 a : 101
test[0]^1 : 4 b : 100
```

I think that test[0] = 100 -> test[0]^1 = 101 but it is not.

```
      100 
  XOR   1
----------
      101
```

Would you expain what is different?

Comment: `test[0]^=1` is a statement, `test[0]^1` is expression.

Comment: After first XOR operation the value in array test[0] is also updated that why after second XOR you get the same result. **test[0]^=1  equivalent to test[0]= test[0] ^ 1**

Comment: I'd like to say, that it's unclear whether your question is "how does `test[0]^=1` work?" or "how do bitwise operators work?". I guess it's both, in your case, but it's always better to clarify what you're exactly asking about, as these two concepts (compound assignment and bitwise) are two, absolutely different topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because test[0] value already changed to `101` because of `test[0]^=1`. `test[0]^=1` which is actually `test[0] = test[0] ^ 1`.  So while doing `b = test[0] ^ 1` you are actually doing `101 ^ 1` which is `100`. So the program output is correct.

```
int [] test = {4};   // test[0] = 4 = 100
int a = test[0]^=1;  // test[0] = 100 ^ 1 = 101 = 5, a = 5 = 101
int b = test[0]^1;   // test[0] = 5, b = 101^1 = 100 = 4
```